# Applying background Image to table cell with VML

Tags: html, email, html-email, vml

I am trying to apply a repeating background to a table cell for an html email, I am  using the code from http://backgrounds.cm/

Here is my TD and wrapper VML:

```
<td background="http://domain.com/Portals/0/emails/images/stripes-middle.png" bgcolor="#00ff00" width="346" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:346px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://domain.com/Portals/0/emails/images/stripes-middle.png" color="#ff0000" />
    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
      <p>LOTS OF CONTENT IN HERE</p>                                                                
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

However, it is renderring my background image up in the top left of the parent table! Not within the table cell.  How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13

Answer (score 1):

why not nest it in another table then?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
<tr valign="top">
    <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="346" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td background="http://domain.com/Portals/0/emails/images/stripes-middle.png" bgcolor="#ff0000" width="346" height="112" valign="top">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"   style="width:346px;height:112;">
                    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://domain.com/Portals/0/emails/images/stripes-middle.png" color="#ff0000" />
                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
                    <div>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="346" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <p>LOTS OF CONTENT IN HERE</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

can't pinpoint exactly where you're going wrong, but I've never used fit-shape-to-text before and this snippet hasn't done me wrong.